# Android null pointer in getfilesdir()

Tags: java, android, pointers, null

I'm am getting a NULL pointer message on getfilesdir().  I'm sure it has something to do with my implementation but I'm not really sure what it is.  Ad I'm extremely new to android development.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String appFileDirectory = getFilesDir().getPath();
String executableFilePath = appFileDirectory + "/iperf3";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    copyFile("iperf3");
}

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

//This function is used to copy the iperf3 executable to a directory which execute permissions for this application, and then gives it execute permissions.
//It runs on every initiation of an iperf3 test, but copies the file only if it's needed.
public void copyFile(String filename) {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream in = assetManager.open(filename);
        File outFile = new File(appFileDirectory, filename);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

        Log.d(TAG, "Attempting to copy this file: " + filename); // + " to: " +       assetCopyDestination);

        int read;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        in.close();

        //After the copy operation is finished we give execute permissions to iPerf3
        File execFile = new File(executableFilePath);
        execFile.setExecutable(true);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
    }
}

public static void executeIperf3() {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try add

```
String appFileDirectory = getFilesDir().getPath();
String executableFilePath = appFileDirectory + "/iperf3";
```

into `onCreate()` because `getFilesDir()` is context method.

Comment: This works if I put it in onCreate() however what would I do if I wanted the strings to be available to other methods and classes?

Comment: You can declare `appFileDirectory` and `executableFilePath` to use for other methods but must put it inside `onCreate()` method.

Comment: As @KrisArmstrong said we must use getFilesDir() in oncreate() method. And if we want to use in other classes we must use context.getFilesDir() instead.